# why comparing two instance of same class return false?

Tags: c#

```
  Consider the below code  -  

 // given class abc
     class abc
        {
          public string firstName {get;set;}
          public string lastName {get;set;}
        }

class program
{
  static void Main()
  {
   var a1 = new abc();   
   var a2 = new abc();  // object of same class


   if (a1==a2)    //always return false
     {
       // some code here
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: try to override == / Equals in your class

Comment: I think what you want is: bool equal2 = typeof(a1) == typeof(a2);

Comment: The assumption what two `new` will create same instance definitely need more answers! Or was it a type check? Post yours asap!

Comment: but if i write like  var a1 = new abc();   
   var a2 = a1, then comparing both two variables give true .

Answer (score 3):

when you  use  `==` you  are comparing the reference not the object content

because the referece is not the same when you are doing this

```
   var a1 = new abc();   
   var a2 = new abc();
```

`a1` has an allocation in  memory(which called instance) and  `a2` has another allocation in  memory  (which it will be another instance)
please take a look at how to  ovveride [GetHashcode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

it's the same class but not the same instance of a class. Supposing you're comparing 2 students each represented by a class

> student

both instances of that class would very probably carry different values, e.g. name, age and that like. These should (for obvious reasons) NOT be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You *have to describe* which class instances are equal, e.g. let two `abc` instances be equal if and only if they have equal `firstName` and `lastName` properties' values:

```
class abc {
  public string firstName { get; set; }
  public string lastName { get; set; }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    abc other = obj as abc;

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, other))
      return false;
    else
      return string.Equals(firstName, other.firstName) &&
             string.Equals(lastName, other.lastName);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (lastName == null ? 0 : lastName.GetHashCode()) ^ 
           (firstName == null ? 0 : firstName.GetHashCode());
  }
}

....

var a1 = new abc();   
var a2 = new abc();  // object of same class

if (a1 == a2) // now it'll return true
{
   // some code here
}

// it'll be still false: a1 and a2 are different references
if (object.ReferenceEquals(a1, a2)) { 
  // some other code here
}
```

If you don't provide `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, .Net will use *referential equality* (instances are equal if they have the same reference): in your case `a1` and `a2` are different references, that's `a1 != a2` by default.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Comment: From what I know it's not mandatory to override `GetHashCode` and even on official msdn page they are writing that it can happen that two completely different objects can have the same hash code.

Comment: @m.rogalski: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx - let us be *nice* and show how to implement `GetHashCode`. "It is recommended that any class that overrides `Equals` also override `System.Object.GetHashCode`"

Comment: I know that it will produce warning messages. But this is the question I'm asking myself everytime I override `Equals` method. "Do I really need to override `GetHashCode`?" is it really that much of a "help" to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object. You should override the operator == if you want to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

```
var alicesBall = new GreenBall();
var bobsBall = new GreenBall();
```

You have two balls now: Alice's ball and Bob's ball. If someone would ask you whether both are the same ball – not the same **kind** – you would probably say "no".

But if someone was to ask whether both have the same kind of ball – in this case a green ball – you would probably answer "of course".

What you want to compare is whether a1 and a2 have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two objects with the == operator compares the address in memory, not the objects themselves. Try using the Object.Equals() method after giving them the same vale or define your own .Equals() method.

From MSDN:

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for
>   reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference
>   equality means the object references that are compared refer to the
>   same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have
>   the same binary representation.
>
> Note that a derived type might override the Equals method to implement
>   value equality. Value equality means the compared objects have the
>   same value even though they have different binary representations. For
>   example, consider two Decimal objects that represent the numbers 1.10
>   and 1.1000. The Decimal objects do not have bitwise equality because
>   they have different binary representations to account for the
>   different number of trailing zeroes. However, the objects have value
>   equality because the numbers 1.10 and 1.1000 are considered equal for
>   comparison purposes since the trailing zeroes are insignificant.

This is a quote from the following: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses/).

"Now, behind the scenes, the CLR actually does implement managed object references as addresses to objects owned by the garbage collector, but that is an implementation detail. There’s no reason why it has to do that other than efficiency and flexibility. C# references could be implemented by opaque handles that are meaningful only to the garbage collector, which, frankly, is how I prefer to think of them. That the “handle” happens to actually be an address at runtime is an implementation detail which I should neither know about nor rely upon. (Which is the whole point of encapsulation; the client doesn’t have to know.)"

As far as the programmer is concerned, it is something other then a pointer/address. but to the compiler it is simply and address. So, while they are used differently (one type safe the other not) they are both pointers as far as the compiler is concerned until Microsoft decides to implement the CLR differently.

Comment: `Comparing two objects with the == operator compares the address in memory` No, it does whatever the type has overloaded it to do.  The same is true of `object.Equals`, it *also* does whatever the type defines it to do (and if not defined, both have the *same* behavior of comparing the references).

Comment: @Servy From a language standpoint yes, they are not addresses to the programmer. They are managed object references. But behind the scenes, yes they are simply a pointer which is simply an address, because Microsoft never bother do implement them properly in the CLR. See edit above.

Comment: Again, no, that's not what the `==` operator does.  The `==` operator *does whatever the author of the class coded it to do*.  They can write it to  compare the values of the fields, or certain fields, or anything else they want to have it do.  Comparing the references to the objects is just the *default* behavior if no other implementation is given.

Comment: @Servy Yes, this is very true. But the point i'm trying to make, language semantics aside, if the author does not define a new compare method, when the code goes to the CLR it then becomes a pointer and is no longer a reference. '==' operator on a pointer compares address. From a high level language standpoint of how C# is supposed to work you are correct. references can not be treated as an address by the author and are treated differently from an implementation standpoint. But behind the scenes, they are implemented as addresses by the compiler and take on those properties.

Comment: And the point *I'm* trying to make is that it's simply wrong to say that the `==` operator compares the references.  It doesn't.  It does whatever it was defined to do.  The `Equals` method does the same, and also has *exactly the same* default behavior if not re-defined, so suggesting that as an alternative wouldn't change anything.  You can talk about the behavior it has *by default*, but that's very different.  The differences between references and addresses aren't relevant here.

Comment: @Servy I see your point and i will have to agree with you. I am wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to compare the objects' attributes.
Here is my suggestion:

```
if (a1.firstName==a2.firstName && a1.lastName == a2.lastName){
   //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to know is that objects ( classes ) are created by reference not value and when you're using `==` comparer it will check for the reference equality when dealing with "by ref" data types because that's the default `Equals` behavior for that data types. ( Hope it makes sense if not I can be more specific ).

To fix your issue you should override `Equals` method to compare values stored inside of your object instead of checking the reference equality.

Example :

```
class abc
{
    public string firstName {get;set;}
    public string lastName {get;set;}

    // custom equality comparer
    public override bool Equals(object other) 
    {
        if ( other is abc )
        {
           abc comparer = other as abc;
           if ( comparer != null )
           {
               return string.Equals(comparer.firstName, this.firstName)
                      &&
                      string.Equals(comparer.lastName, this.lastName);
           }
        }
        return base.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have two different objects in two different memory location.

You can use GetType() and typeof () to compare classes.

Comment: Aren't those Java methods?

Comment: The question has the C# tag :)

Comment: Oh, my fault. What a mistake. I corrected my answer

Comment: There's no method called `getType` in C# but the fitting one would be `GetType`.